# Is there a .NET control similar to Firefox's Address/Location/Awesome bar?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, firefox, controls

Is there a .NET component out there that is similar to Firefox's location bar?

I need all the features of the Firefox address bar, but I want to control the "history" from which the suggestions are made.

This is for Winforms or WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it; it's effectively just an editable ComboBox. It would be pretty easy to replicate in WPF.

Is there any part of the control you think would be difficult to implement?

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to implement the control from scratch, but I guess it won't be all that difficult in WPF.